# mono_delegate_to_ftnptr: function call hangs

Tags: mono, interop, unmanaged, managed, internal

I'm embedding mono 2.10.8 into my application and have some troubles with functions, registered with `mono_add_internal_call`

Let's say i have managed method:

```
internal delegate void Win32ServiceHandler(long statusCode);

internal static class Win32Service
{
  [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
  public static extern void Test(Win32ServiceHandler handler);
}
```

it's unmanaged definition:

```
void icall_TestDelegateCallback(MonoDelegate *ftn) {
  LPHANDLER_FUNCTION f = (LPHANDLER_FUNCTION)mono_delegate_to_ftnptr(ftn);
  f(SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP);
}
```

and some code to test:

```
protected virtual void ServiceHandler(Win32ServiceControl statusCode)
{   
  Console.WriteLine("here");
}

public void MakeTest()
{
  Console.WriteLine("before");
  Win32Service.Test(this.ServiceHandlerInternal);
  Console.WriteLine("after");
}
```

I run it from console application and when i call MakeTest(), the output is:

```
before
here
```

And application never return.

Actually it is a simplified eexample. In real program i need to pass function pointer as a callback to `RegisterServiceCtrlHandler` so stuff like `mono_runtime_invoke` (that btw works fine) etc isn't what i need.

The question is what is the proper way to call a function pointer obtained from MonoDelegate? Or is it any other correct way to pass it as a callback?

My platform is Windows 7 x64

**UPD:**

Interesting finding. Once i change my code to:

```
internal static class Win32Service
{
  [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
  public static extern void Test(Action handler);
}
```

and

```
typedef VOID (*TESTFTN)();

void icall_TestDelegateCallback(MonoDelegate *ftn) {
  TESTFTN f = (TESTFTN)mono_delegate_to_ftnptr(ftn);
  f();
}
```

and:

```
public void MakeTest()
{
  Console.WriteLine("before");
  Win32Service.Test(() => Console.WriteLine("here"));
  Console.WriteLine("after");
}
```

Everithing works great. So the problem is in marshalling long to DWORD? In this how it can be solved?

Answer (score 0):

A DWORD is a 32bit integer type, while a long in C# is a 64 bit type.